# Removing Rows when cell is empty

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to remove a row in a sorted table if a cell in a given column is empty.

I got it so far that the row isn't displayed any more if I don't sort the table. But if I sort it the wrong row is removed. I think it has something to do with the order in which the things are done, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}, 
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}


\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
        1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
        1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
        1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
        1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
        1010127; 3.0; 5;
        1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
        1010125; 2.5; 7; 9
    }\Marks

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}]\Marks

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\Marks}
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}]\Marks

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\Marks}
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    sort, sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <}, columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}]\Marks
\end{document}
```

The code creates these three tabulars:

[image: Tabulars in different states]

The first shows it completely, the second is the table without sorting, the last is where all comes together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities. If you need the unsorted table, you can add the line

```
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <}]\MarksSorted\MarksUnsorted
```

after the table, to additionally get the sorted table. Or, if you don't need the unsorted table, you can change

```
\pgfplotstableread{ ... }\MarksUnsorted
```

to

```
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <}]\MarksSorted{ ... }
```

(see commented part in the code below).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}, 
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}


\begin{document}
% no unsorted table available
%    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <}]\MarksSorted{
%        ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
%        1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
%        1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
%        1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
%        1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
%        1010127; 3.0; 5;
%        1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
%        1010125; 2.5; 7; 9
%    }

% both, sorted and unsorted table available
    \pgfplotstableread{
        ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
        1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
        1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
        1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
        1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
        1010127; 3.0; 5;
        1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
        1010125; 2.5; 7; 9
    }\MarksUnsorted
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <}]\MarksSorted\MarksUnsorted

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\MarksUnsorted}% <-- spurious space removed
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}]\MarksUnsorted
{ }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\MarksSorted}% <-- spurious space removed
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}]\MarksSorted
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can save the table without the removed row to a file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}, 
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

\newcommand{\addsumcol}[3]{%
    % #1=table name
    % #2=first column name
    % #3=name of new column
    % Sums for each column
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[%
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \def\entry{}%
        \def\colsum{0}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}%
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {#2,...,\maxcolindex}{%
            \IfStrEq{\thisrowno{\col}}{}% check if the cell is empty
            {}% true
            {\pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}}% false
        }%
        \xdef\entry{\colsum}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
    ]{#3}#1%
}%

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
        1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
        1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
        1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
        1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
        1010127; 3.0; 5;
        1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
        1010125; 2.5; 7; 9
    }\Marks

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}, 
    columns/Mark/.style={numeric type, fixed zerofill, precision=1}]\Marks

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\Marks}
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}, 
    columns/Mark/.style={numeric type, fixed zerofill, precision=1}
    ]\Marks

    \pgfplotstablesave[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Points 3}\of{\Marks}
        \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{}%
        {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%true
        {}%false
    },
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3},
    col sep=semicolon
    ]\Marks{marks.csv}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    sort, sort key={ID}, sort cmp={int <},
    columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3}, 
    columns/Mark/.style={numeric type, fixed zerofill, precision=1}
    ]{marks.csv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! As you said it is a workaround. Maybe someone finds a better solution, or do you think it is a bug, that should be reported?